# Food Vacuum Storage Systems

Tags: storage-method, food-preservation, storage

What do consumers need to keep in mind when shopping for food vacuum storage systems? It seems FoodSaver is the most well received brand with the largest market share in the food storage space, however are there any other noteworthy features or qualities with other systems?

Comment: ["gas flush"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_packing)

Comment: Ability to vacuum and seal retort (perhaps microwaveable -poly) bags, domed wiring is better than flat banded wires. [video ref](https://youtu.be/HclAVJ_22pY)

Comment: Retort bags require 1/2" seal to withstand canning, rather than many that offer 1/8". Also they require dual-wiring. [ref](https://www.amazon.com/Will-seal-Retort-Pouch/forum/Fx1ZRL8K6PBJ147/Tx35LVCPIWA2M3P/1?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B003YE8FG0).

Comment: see: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8028/are-any-retail-vacuum-sealing-systems-worth-the-expense